# SynchronizedSet in apache commons

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, apache-commons

Why is there [Apache's Synchronized Set](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/set/SynchronizedSet.html) when we have [Collection's SynchronizedSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet%28java.util.Set%29)?

Is it better in any way?

Comment: Ok, than say: can you do something with the Apache's version, which you cannot do with the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is because it allows you to specify a custom lock object.

The constructor is protected but you can subclass it and pass a custom lock.

Comment: Well, good point, but when you need a custom lock object, you will need external synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do. Apache's synchronized set allows you to get the underlying set. It is probably provide for consistency. The Collections method is standard.

You might consider using one of the concurrent sets like `Collections.setFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap())`,  `CopyOnWriteArraySet` or `ConcurrentSkipListSet`

Comment: I don't think you can access the underlying set. See http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/set/SynchronizedSet.html#getSet%28%29: Gets the **decorated** set.

Comment: @pihentagy, That means the same thing to me. Here is the source http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Library/Apache-common-Collections/org/apache/commons/collections/set/SynchronizedSet.java.htm

Comment: Lwarey: Confused. Docs says you get the decorated set, but code says you get the undecorated one. Is there a typo in the docs then?

Comment: I would read it as meaning; the set which has been *decorated*, rather than the set which is *decorating* it.